# Comparing unit root tests

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

When comparing the results of different unit root tests (in this case DF-GLS test with  and ADF test), should I keep the lag length fixed for both tests, or am-I allowed to use predefined/suggested lag lengths? If I am obliged to take the same fixed lag length for both tests, is the following approximation fine?

(sample size)^(1/3) -1

Comment: Is there a reason for 4 lags in ADF and 13 in the other? If no theoretical justification, or no empirical reasoning, why not let the max lag be as high as 13 and allow an information criterion to choose the optimal lag.

Comment: just edited the question, i am familiar with ADF and there we used the amount of lags as suggested by the formula as each ARMA process can be approximated by (sample size)^(1/3)  , then we substract 1 extra obs as adf uses differences. i am not familliar with DF-GLS (ERS) test and thus I just chose the max lag length as a test. however results are better when i use fewer lags in df gls. so for using the 13 lags, no there was no real reason.

Comment: @mr.rox -> if the lag length is automatically selected, will the criterion select the same lag length for whatever technique? if so, my problem is solved.

Comment: It may not select uniform lag order. You should realise that the lag order is only there to keep the residuals in line with the OLS assumptions i.e. white noise. In some cases you will see that the hypothesis test on the coefficient of interest in the unit root test is unchanged regardless of the lag order.

Comment: allright, thus i'm allowed to compare the results of an ADF test and a DF-GLS test while using the same intercept/trend specification and the same information criterion (e.g. sbc)

Comment: Yes, you can, but as long as the trend and intercept assumptions are the same in both tests, you are fine. Also, you may want to watch this video on ADF test https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ePFfyGxz4I